# USB Touchscreens - Unknown Device after PC has been off overnight

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I'm out of leads on this problem, and I'm hoping someone will read this and know what to look for.

**The Problem**

I have two machines. Both machines are identical in terms of software, hardware, and peripherals.
Each machine has three identical touchscreens connected via a USB hub.

If I shut down the machines in the evening, and then turn them on in the morning, one of the machines (always the same one) will usually have at least one of the touchscreens as an "Unknown Device" in Windows 7 Device Manager, and needless to say, the failed touchscreen(s) don't work. The other machine works perfectly every time.

**The Plot Thickens...**

It only happens to the one machine, and it can be any of the touchscreens on that machine that are affected.
It only seems to happen after the machine has been off for some time. If you restart the machine, or shut down then turn back on soon after, the touchscreens all work.

If you switch the peripherals over, so that the touchscreens are now plugged into the opposite machines, it is still the same machine that has failed touchscreens on start-up.

The touchscreen will stay in a failed state until power is removed and re-applied to the touchscreen controller card.

It is only the touchscreens that are affected. Both machines have various other USB peripherals, but never have any problems being enumerated.

There are no 3rd party touchscreen drivers, and I've even tried with disabling the default Microsoft drivers. The problem seems to happen during the Windows USB Core Stack Enumeration.

I've followed [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2012/08/07/how-to-trace-usb-3-activity.aspx) to get logs from the Core Windows USB Driver Stack, and the resulting logs between a successful boot and one where touchscreens failed are pretty much identical, right up until Windows requests the Device Descriptor. At that point, the touchscreen from a successful boot log returns its Descriptor, whereas a failed one returns Stall, but before that they both seems to be doing the same thing.

I really don't know what else to try to solve this problem, or to try and find out what the difference is between the machines that is causing the problem.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Click the battery icon -> Click more power options ->click change plab setting ->click change advanced power settings -> click usb settings ->click usb selective suspend settings, change to disable.

Also if possible in your bios enable all the options related to usb, like "wake USB after sleep" etc. (Cannot tell you exactly, as each bios is different).

EDIT: Also in the device manager, in the driver properties, in power management tab, un-check "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Hope my answer helped.

Comment: +1 I've tried the selective suspend before and it didn't make a difference, but still a good point to check. All of the BIOS USB settings were already enabled, so I've disabled all but the minimum required. I'll see if it's made a difference when it next boots up. Thanks.

Comment: I can only guess, but I reckon the USB does not receive enough power after sleep. I would not say it is a driver problem as the screens work fine on the other system. Can you connect the screen directly to the system instead of the usb hub and see if the problem recurs. Another recommendation would be use a powered usb hub(the one that has external power source in addition to the usb port).

Comment: Turns out the screens were not CE marked, and the issue was due to electromagnetic interference. This was picked up during EMC testing. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem :) Just update your solution as a comment below your question, so that others having similar problems can get to the solution.